# How to read from file, turn into a dictionary and write to the same file

Tags: python, text, dictionary

```
[Running Python 2.7 on MacOSX]
```

Hey there,

I'm trying to read and write from/to the same file.
What my plan is, is basically that I will read the contents of a text file, put it into a dictionary, then edit this dictionary and then put it back into the text file to be read into a dictionary elsewhere.

I haven't done something quite like this before so I need some ideas, perhaps visual examples (I would appreciate this greatly). 

An example of what I want to do:

```
Apple  Green
Lemon  Yellow
Grape  Purple
```

Now I need to conver this into a dictionary some how, let's call it fruit

```
fruit = {'Apple' : 'Green', 'Lemon' : 'Yellow', 'Grape' : 'Purple'}
```

Now we want to change the colour of say Apple to Red?

```
fruit = {'Apple' : 'Red', 'Lemon' : 'Yellow', 'Grape' : 'Purple'}
```

And finally put it back into the text file / overwrite the previous text file, so it can then later be opened elsewhere and made into a new dictionary to be used:

```
Apple  Red
Lemon  Yellow
Grape  Purple
```

What I really need, is to find the best way to do this, I haven't quite done anything yet in my attempts, so I'm seeking a bit of advice. **This last step, to convert the dictionary back into that format is what I'm not being able to do.**

Thanks,

*zahz*

Comment: Those three steps you mentioned seem like a reasonable approach.

Comment: I know, but getting them is what I can't seem to do. Especially turning it back into it's original format, the rest I shouldn't have an issue with.

Comment: Do you want the text file to be human-readable or only readable by your Python program ? For the latter, you can use [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html).

Comment: OrderedDict might be slightly useful, but not necessary.

Comment: Do you need to retain order, or it does not matter?

Comment: @zahz So you have a pre-populated dict that you're trying to write to a text file. Give it a try, then come back if you're having problems.

Comment: The text file itself does not have to be human readable, I will just need it to output at a later stage, using another function I'll write.
I'll look into Pickle, although I can't say I've used it before - I'll try familiarise myself.

Comment: I do not need to retain order, as long as all the keys and values are intact, it's just fine.

Comment: With Pickle it's extremely simple : `import pickle`, then to load a file : `data = pickle.load(open("filename", "rb"))`, and to save data to a file : `pickle.dump(data, open("filename", "wb"))`. And it'll work with any Python object, not just dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the file into a dictionary is pretty simple. Here's a simple way to do it:

```
d = {}
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        key, value = line.split()
        d[key] = value
```

A more concise way to do the same thing:

```
d = dict(map(str.split, open(filename)))
```

This does not explicitly `.close` the file with a with-block, instead Python will close the file when it is garbage collected IIRC.

Writing the file out is similarly simple:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for key, value in d.items():
        f.write('{}  {}\n'.format(key, value))
```

Or again, more concisely:

```
open(filename, 'w').write('\n'.join('{}  {}'.format(key, d[key]) for key in d))
```

This takes a different approach, writing out the whole dictionary as one string, where the iterative version writes it out one line at a time. Which one is better is up to you.

Comment: `f.truncate()` isn't necessary when opening a file in `w` mode since it already overwrites it.

Comment: Ah, thanks you're right. I usually put it there out of habit. Removed :)

Comment: Answer Accepted. 
Thank you, you've explained it very well with different methods to go about it. Helpful.